# "3 state" command line arguments in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing an application that needs access to Internet. From some hosts the connection needs to go through proxy. I know that proxy can be set on an environment variable, but I want to do it from the application itself.
I need a command line argument that can be used in three different ways:

1. not given at all -> no proxy
2. --use-proxy -> use default proxy
3. --use-proxy "http://my-proxy.com:880" -> uses given proxy

Following uses default or given address but cannot be used to ignore proxy:

> use_proxy := flag.String("use-proxy", "http://my-proxy.com:880", "Use proxy...")

This one accomplishes only points 1 & 2:

```
use_proxy := flag.Bool("use-proxy", false , "Use proxy...")
if *use_proxy {
  ...
  proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://my-proxy.com:880")
  ...
}
```

The problem could be solved with two flags but I'd rather use just one:

> myapp --use-proxy --proxy "http://my-proxy.com:880"

Comment: The problem is the parser won't accept parameters without value. You need at least the `=` as in `myapp --use-proxy=`. Then you can make the distinction with no flag passed.

Comment: How would your app interpret  a command line like `myapp --use-proxy --some-other-flag`?

Comment: A precision regarding my last comment : the parser accept parameters without value but only for Val of type `boolValue` (it's hardcoded).

Comment: There are some linux applications that can take arguments that way. Not sure if this is very good example but first that I came up with: 'ls --color' or 'ls --color=yes'. This probably needs to be done by parsing os.Args

Comment: The `--color` option to ls actually demonstrates the problem: `ls --color=yes` and `ls --color yes` do different things, contrary to the regular handling of long options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app definitely won't use any other command line arguments, then you can just make `--use-proxy` a boolean flag, and then get the proxy URL from the first command line argument, i.e. from `os.Args`.

This probably isn't a good idea long term though, as it restricts adding additional arguments/options to your program.

Most argument parsers won't handle a case like this, since it makes parsing command line options ambiguous.

Other options could be to allow a keyword for the default value, e.g.:

```
myapp --use-proxy "http://my-proxy.com:880"
myapp --use-proxy default
```

or to use two options, both of which enable the proxy, but having only one take an argument, e.g.:

```
myapp --use-proxy <proxy URL>
myapp --use-default-proxy
```